# How to use state values in another file

Tags: reactjs, forms, state

I created a file for a registration form  and I want to make use of / display the state values in another file without rendering what's in the file. Thanks for your opinions in advance

```
import Profile from './profilePage.js';
class reg extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             name:"",
             country:"America",
        }
    }
    nameChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            firstname : e.target.value,
        })
    }
  
    countryChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            country : e.target.value,
        })
    }
    formSubmitted = (event)=>{
        alert(`Welcome ${this.state.name}`);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="regForm">
      <form onSubmit={this.formSubmitted}>
       <label htmlFor="Fname">First Name:</label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="enter first name" id="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.nameChange} required/>
               
      <select id="country" value={this.state.country} onChange={this.countryChange} >
            <option>America</option>
            <option>Spain</option>
      </select>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
             <Profile country ={this.state.country} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default reg
```

then this is the sample of the file i want to use the state value in is like this

```
class profilePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super({country})
    
        this.state = {
             
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (

            <div className="profileInfo">
            <div className="profileDetails">
    <p><b>Country:</b> {this.props.country} </p>
            </div>
            </div>
          
        )
    }
}
```

This worked but it kept rendering what was in my profilePage file, in which I understand why it renders it. so, please I'm looking for a better and more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Everytime `country` state is updated, a re-render is triggered in `<profilePage />`. But what are you asking about?

Comment: @codemax i want to use the value gotten from the form in the profile page without it displaying / returning what is in the profile page on the registration page

Comment: So you don't want it the value `this.props.country` to be displayed?